# REST vs Android API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

What's the difference in using the android API and the REST API? Are they equivalent? Can I do the same thing in both?

What are the limitations of one and the other?

I intend to start developing a mobile APP with HERE MAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 flavours of the HERE Mobile SDKs at the moment: Starter and Premium edition.

The starter edition is more or less identical to the REST interfaces and is using it also under the hood. It takes away all the boilerplate code you'd have to write (map tiling, fetching tiles and tile scrolling, REST requests to al the services and converting it into local objects, and so on).

The premium edition is using the HERE Hybrid engine instead. This means a lot of the services also work offline and run directly on your device, the mapdata is a special vector format that is also downloaded on your device, and you use online services and offline services mixed.

The premium edition has (beside offline capabilities) also some additional features you won't get in REST or in starter SDK, like turn by turn guidance or LiveSight.

Comment: I will use Flutter, for which there is no plugin, so I only have to use the HERE REST API.
Is there a premium version of the REST API, with the additional features you mentioned?

Comment: No, for Guidance and LiveSight you would need to build on top of the Premium Mobile SDK.